# Wordpress use standard rewrite and then set function to do rewrite page_id

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, url-rewriting

I need to use wordpress with standard rewrite rules like that "http://www.mysite.com/?p=123"
, but i want to rewrite content like "http://www.mysite.com/store", but i don't want to use internal function of wordpress like "http://www.mysite.com/postname"
, i will rewrite in .htacess, so i wrote that so the content gets rewrited,

```
function replace_mycontent($string){
    $pattern = '/?page_id=([^/]+)/';  // urls like http://www.mysite.com/?p=123
    $replacement = '/$1/'; // gets replaced by http://www.mysite/store
return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_mycontent');
```

This gives errors, some help welcome,

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code:  `$pattern = '/?page_id=([^/]+)/';`

with this: `$pattern = '/?p=([^/]+)/';`

**EDIT 1:**

In .htaccess, this can be done as *(Considering, Wordpress is installed in the site's root directory*):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
<IfModule>
```

Comment: Not working, i think the problem is that appears, that in standard mode wordpress as /?p=123 but keeps rewriting to /?page_id=123, so what to search in content ? I Just want to rewrite /?p=123 or /?page_id=123 to store, without ending slash like this www.mysite/store.

Comment: I tested and no good, i think that the function is not being used, the code is inside a plugin, is the only code inside the plugin, maybe something is missing.